# Create a new avro schema using Kafka schema-registry API

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, avsc

I am trying to create a new schema using the kafka-schema-registery api. I followed the steps mentioned in this post. [Register a new avro schema using Kafka schema-registry API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797670/register-a-new-avro-schema-using-kafka-schema-registry-api)

My Avro Schema:

```
{
  "doc": "Sample schema to help you get started.",
  "fields": [
    {
      "doc": "The id of the order.",
      "name": "orderId",
      "type": "int"
    }
  ],
  "name": "sampleRecord",
  "namespace": "com.mycorp.mynamespace",
  "type": "record"
}
```

Input parser:

```
 const inputSchemaJson = {
            "schema": JSON.stringify(inputSchema)
          };
```

Below is the implementation :

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
                hostname: hostName,
                path: '/subjects/' + schemaName + '/versions',
                method: 'POST',
                json: true,
                body: inputSchemaJson,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authorizationHeader
                }
            };"

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        let inputSchemaJson = '';

        console.log('Status Code:', res.statusCode);

        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            inputSchemaJson += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('Body: ', JSON.parse(inputSchemaJson));
        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: ", err.message);
    });

    req.write(inputSchemaJson);
    req.end();
```

But getting below error, Any suggestions.

```
 _http_outgoing.js:696
  throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
        ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is self-descriptive

> argument must be of type string ... Received an instance of Object

You're POST-ing a Javascript object. You'll need to completely stringify `inputSchemaJson`